# Difference between "spine" and "backbone"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns

Is there a difference between *spine* and *backbone* in use or in meaning? I think they both mean the same and can be replaced by each other. However, I'd say *backbone* is used more in figurative speech, but this is just a guess on my part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Backbone* and *spine* are both common names for the *vertebral column*, the series of bones from one's head to pelvis. In my personal opinion, *backbone* comes across as more of an informal name than *spine*.

It is worth noting that both of these words, however, have other meanings as well:

- *Spine* can also be used to refer to a needle-like protrusion on plants and animals (among other things) such as a thorn. It can also reference the bound edge of a book.
- *Backbone* can also be used to refer to nearly any fundamental support structure. For example, an *internet backbone*, which is the top level of inter-connectivity between core pieces of the internet.

Comment: Yes, like many of our words, the Latinate one (*spine*) is the more elite form, while the Germanic one (*backbone*) is more informal.

Answer (score 3):

The term "backbone" is pretty much restricted to a single idiom: to "[show some backbone](http://englishidiomsblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/show-some-backbone.html)," which means to be brave or resolute.

In this phrase, you can substitute the word "spine," and the meaning is unchanged. In almost any other conceivable instance, you'll want the word "spine," as in, "she injured her spine in the accident."

Edit: The above only refers to mammalian physiology. Figurative or metaphorical uses of "backbone," such as "ATT is the backbone of the Internet" or such is a different matter.

Comment: Also worth noting that, adjectivally, the subject of your idiom would be considered _spineless_.

Comment: I'd say I hear backbone used about as much as spine far beyond the context of this idiom.

Comment: @Karl: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=spine%2C+backbone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: I would expect spine to be used more commonly in medical settings, hence its appearance in more books. A quick look at the references supports this quite well. On the street though, I would say they both enjoy frequent use.

Comment: It's funny that in denoting bravery or courage, 'spine' and 'backbone' are interchangeable ... However, to indicate the opposite, you would say that somebody was either  'spineless', **or** 'lacking in backbone'.
(I certainly have never heard anyone accuse another of being 'backboneless'.)

Comment: @brachomonacho I would have said that _spineless_ was far more common usage than _lacking in backbone_; the latter might be as infrequent as _backboneless_.

Answer (score 1):

As reported by the NOAD, the meaning of *backbone* is:

- the series of vertebrae extending from the skull to the pelvis
- (figurative) the chief support of a system or organization; the mainstay
- (figurative) strength of character; firmness
- the spine of a book

For those meanings, there is a similar meaning for *spine*.

In zoology and botany, *spine* is also any hard pointed defensive projection or structure, while in geology it means also "a tall mass of viscous lava extruded from a volcano."
In biochemistry, *backbone* means also "the main chain of a polymeric molecule."